# css scroll with overflow property does not work

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll, overflow

I am trying to have a vertical scrollbar in the body of page. which should be implemented by css.

I don't want to use fixed height.

I used following code in my css:

```
.summary-scroll {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   height: 100%;
}
```

but it does not work. 
But when I add just an attribute named: layout="column"  (without any need to have class attribute) the body has scrollbar.

I don't know what is the relation between layout and scrolling?
Also I have to implement it in my css , what is the solution for handling in css file?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
.body-scroll{ max-height:600px; 
             height: 100% !important; 
             overflow-y: scroll; 
              overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, by it still doesn't work. scroll just be visible when I set fixed height(like heigh:600px)

Comment: .body-scroll {
    max-height:600px
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}<div  class="body-scroll" layout="column">

    <ng-content select="sei-body"></ng-content>

</div>

Comment: .body-scroll{max-height:600px; height: 100% !important; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;}  please try this

Comment: Thanks,it works now, is't any way to not use static size for height?I wanted to use just height:100% .

Comment: @Maryam Gharibi if it  works fine for you can update point this answer Thanks !!